# failed to reload file and fpdf output is not working

Tags: php, mysql, action, fpdf

I'm trying create a pdf file after the form execute all validation and submit the form. If I put form.php in action, all the validation will not execute. But if a made a script alert with the window.location, it will execute but the output pdf is failed to reload.

This is what I mean:

```js
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
                echo 'alert("registered");'; 
                echo 'window.location.href = "form.php";';
                echo '</script>';
```

form.php

```
 <?php
include('includes/connections.php');
        $date = date('l | F d, Y h:i A');
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $midname = $_POST['midname'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $nfather = $_POST['nfather'];
        $nmother = $_POST['nmother'];
        $guardian = $_POST['guardian'];
        $contactnum = $_POST['contactnum'];
        $relationship = $_POST['relationship'];
        $bday = $_POST['bday'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $status = $_POST['status'];

ob_start();
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

        $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont('Times','B',14);

        $pdf->Ln();
        $pdf->Image('images/logo.png',93,10,30,30);

        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','B',14);
        $pdf ->SetLeftMargin(20);
        $pdf->Ln(14);
        $pdf->Cell(0, 1, "PERSONAL INFORMATION:", 0, 0, 'L');

        $pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
        $pdf->SetLeftMargin(40);
        $pdf->Ln(8);
        $pdf->Cell(0, 1, "LAST NAME: $lname", 0, 0, 'L');
        $pdf->Ln(8);
        $pdf->Cell(0,1,"FIRST NAME: $fname",0,0,'L');
        $pdf->Ln(8);
        $pdf->Cell(0,1,"MIDDLE INITIAL: $midname",0,0,'L');


        $pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
        $pdf->SetLeftMargin(40);
        $pdf->Ln(8);
        $pdf->Cell(0, 1, "ADDRESS: $address", 0, 0, 'L');

        $pdf->Ln(8);
        $pdf->Cell(0,1,"NAME OF FATHER: $nfather",0,0,'L');

        $pdf->Ln(8);
        $pdf->Cell(0,1,"NAME OF MOTHER: $nmother",0,0,'L');

        $pdf->Ln(8);
        $pdf->Cell(0, 1, "BIRTHDAY: $bday", 0, 0, 'L');

        $pdf->Ln(8);
        $pdf->Cell(0, 1, "GENDER: $gender", 0, 0, 'L');

        $pdf->Ln(8);
        $pdf->Cell(0, 1, "STATUS: $status", 0, 0, 'L');

        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','B',14);
        $pdf ->SetLeftMargin(20);
        $pdf->Ln(14);
        $pdf->Cell(0, 1, "IN CASE OF EMERGENCY:", 0, 0, 'L');

        $pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
        $pdf ->SetLeftMargin(40);
        $pdf->Ln(8);
        $pdf->Cell(0, 1, "NAME OF GUARDIAN: $guardian", 0, 0, 'L');

        $pdf->Ln(8);
        $pdf->Cell(0, 1, "CONTACT NUMBER: $contactnum", 0, 0, 'L');

        $pdf->Ln(8);
        $pdf->Cell(0, 1, "RELATIONSHIP: $relationship", 0, 0, 'L');


        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','B',14);
        $pdf ->SetLeftMargin(20);
        $pdf->Ln(14);
        $pdf->Cell(0, 1, "OTHER REQUIREMENTS:", 0, 0, 'L');

        $pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
        $pdf ->SetLeftMargin(40);
        $pdf->Ln(8);
        $pdf->Cell(0, 1, "____ Good Moral", 0, 0, 'L');

        $pdf->Ln(8);
        $pdf->Cell(0, 1, "____ Form 137 / Card", 0, 0, 'L');

        $pdf->Ln(8);
        $pdf->Cell(0, 1, "____ Birth Certificate / PSA", 0, 0, 'L');

        $pdf->Ln(8);
        $pdf->Cell(0, 1, "____ Dengvaxia Record", 0, 0, 'L');


        $pdf->SetRightMargin(20);
        $pdf->Ln(14);
        $pdf->Cell(0, 1, "_______________________", 0, 0, 'R');
        $pdf->SetRightMargin(28);
        $pdf->Ln(6);
        $pdf->Cell(0, 1, "Signature of Student", 0, 0, 'R');


        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','B',12);
        $pdf ->SetLeftMargin(20);
        $pdf->Ln(14);
        $pdf->Cell(0, 1, "DATE AND TIME REGISTERED:", 0, 0, 'L');
        $pdf->Ln(8);
        $pdf->Cell(0, 1, "$date", 0, 0, 'L');

        $pdf->Output("D", "form.pdf");
?>
```

So here. It store's to my db but the output pdf failed to reload..

Comment: What errors, if any, do you get? Turn on error reporting if you haven't already (`ini_set('display_errors','1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);`).

Comment: it only says failed to load file when i tried to open the pdf file

Comment: add EXIT. before this line $pdf->Output("D", "form.pdf");. it will display errors message.